# Where is Gradle finding 'proguard-android-optimize.txt'?

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

I'm not using Android Studio.
I'm using Gradle: gradle-5.5.1 on Windows.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
```

(local.properties)

```
sdk.dir=C:\\android-sdk-wind
```

Enabled in my release builds:

```
minifyEnabled true
```

So I try to modify the 'proguard-android-optimize.txt' in
my

```
c:/android-sdk-wind/tools/proguard
```

and my changes don't do anything, I tried to change:

```
#-optimizationpasses 5
-optimizationpasses 1
```

It isn't using R8, I'm using 3.3.0.
I tried using

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
```

but my build environment didn't like it.

So where is the file I need to modify located,
or how do I modify my:

```
proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
```

to point to the actual file I need to modify?
Or, if I have to, another way to stuck in a .pro file or some other
way to modify the Proguard optimizations for my project?

I tried:

```
proguardFile 'proguard-android-optimize.txt'
```

But that didn't seem to work.

I did read this under "R8 configuration files":

"The Android Gradle plugin generates proguard-android-optimize.txt, which includes rules that are useful to most Android projects..."
That would resolve the "mystery" of where it's getting it from,
but is there a way to modify it?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check in proguard-rules.pro in app

Comment: It doesn't have any defined. I did locate a default one though, in another project.  Can I easily dump my optimize.txt into it, or point to it from there?

Comment: can you try minifyEnabled  true in app's build.gradle, this will activate proguard, IMO this should take default proguard file

Comment: I already have that enabled for my release builds, should have mentioned that.  I've tried everything and have no idea where it's getting it's optimization info, getting really frustrated..  It doesn't like my .pro file in any location, with using ",  'proguard-rules.pro'"

Comment: I was finally able to get it to accept:  proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at another article and it mentioned:

"getDefaultProguardFile() is a simple helper method that fetches them out of build/intermediates/proguard-files. The Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) puts them there."

So I went into that directory, and you can modify:
"proguard-android-optimize.txt-3.3.3"

BUT, as soon as you hit "Clean" on your project, it's gone
and replaced with another default version.

***** UPDATE *****

After much digging I stumbled onto this!:

proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'

Just add that to your build.gradle file, in your app directory, in your release section and rename the whole proguard-android-optimize.txt-3.3.3
and modify it how you want, and put it in the same app
directory and it'll use that!!

Answer (score 0):

The answer of question: Where is Gradle finding 'proguard-android-optimize.txt'?

please check [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/master/files/proguard-android-optimize.txt).